# JS Regex combining

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have such string with requirements to exclude anything except

**a-zA-Z0-9,**

special characters

**()+-.,‘?/:**

Also double or more slashes should be restricted
And string should not start and end with slash.

Example:

```
var str = "///a/ab*/*/bc:dD:123a///'Ad/,.?/!//";

//if I use js replace with regex rule twice I get needed result

"///a/ab*/*/bc:dD:123a///'Ad,.?/!//"
   .replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z()+-.,‘?/:]/g, "")
   .replace(/[^\/+|\/+$|\/{2,}]/g, "");

//result 
"a/abbc:dD:123aAd/,.?"

**Is it possible to combine these rules into one regex rule?!**

//tried to combine these rules by '|' but get failure result

"///a/ab*/*/bc:dD:123a///'Ad/,.?/!//"
   .replace(/([^0-9a-zA-Z()+-.,‘?/:])|^\/+|\/+$|\/{2,}/g, "")
//result
"a/ab//bc:dD:123aAd/,.?/"
```

Comment: Try `.replace(/^\/+|\/+$|\/{2,}|[^0-9a-zA-Z()+.,‘?\/:-]+/g, "")`

Comment: Get "a/ab//bc:dD:123aAd/,.?/"
Slash at the end, double slashes

Comment: Yes, but the double backslash appeared because of `*` removal, they were not consecutive in the first place.

Comment: That's why I want firstly use [^0-9a-zA-Z()+.,‘?\/:-] than regex for slashes

Comment: Try `.replace(/^\/+|(^|[^\/])\/(?:[^0-9a-zA-Z()+.,‘?\/:-]+\/)*\/+$|\/{2,}|\/(?:[^0-9a-zA-Z()+.,‘?\/:-]+\/(?!\/))+|[^0-9a-zA-Z()+.,‘?\/:-]+/g, "$1")`. I get `"a/abbc:dD:123aAd/,.?"`

Comment: thank you, the pattern is complicated but it seems to work without issues!

Comment: You may shorten it greatly if building dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```js
var str = "///a/ab*/*/bc:dD:123a///'Ad/,.?/!//";
var na = "[^0-9a-zA-Z()+.,‘?/:-]+";
var reg = new RegExp("/+$|^/+|(^|[^/])/(?:" + na + "/)*/+$|/{2,}|/(?:" + na + "/(?!/))+|" + na, "g");
console.log(str.replace(reg, "$1"));
```

**Details**

- `/+$` - 1+ `/` chars at the end of the string
- `|` - or
- `^/+` - matches 1+ `/` at the start of the string
- `|` - or
- `(^|[^/])/(?:[^0-9a-zA-Z()+.,‘?/:-]+/)*/+$` - a start of string or any non-`/` char (captured into `$1`) followed with `/` followed with 1 or more repetitions of 1+ chars other than the sets/ranges in the character class and a `/` not followed with another `/` and then 1+ `/` at the end of the string
- `|` - or
- `/{2,}` - any 2 or more slashes
- `|` - or
- `/(?:[^0-9a-zA-Z()+.,‘?/:-]+/(?!/))+` - a `/` followed with 1 or more repetitions of 1+ chars other than the sets/ranges in the character class and a `/` not followed with another `/`
- `|` - or
- `[^0-9a-zA-Z()+.,‘?/:-]+` - 1+ chars other than the sets/ranges in the character class

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/jOYVLu/3).